# Is it possible to do h264 encoding on the fly and send the video over websocket network?

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, rtp, codec

I have already build a test application that can send message packets over UDP using RTP. Now I want to send webcam frames over this connection. I am able to capture individual frames and encode them to JPEG format and send over network.

But this requires high network bandwidth of around 5Mbps to stream with 360p res with refresh rate of 5 frames per second.

Thus now I am looking to use 1sec of buffer frames and encode them using h264 and send it remote user who will then decode the received packet and display the received frames.

I have been exploring options with FFMPEG but couldn't find any proper documentation that fits my requirement. It always need FFMPEG.exe to be involved which will output the encoded file and save it on local disk... I need to be more like what I am doing with JPEG encoding.

Edit: included code snippet

```
    RTPUDPv4TransmissionParams transparams;
    RTPSessionParams sessparams;

    sessparams.SetOwnTimestampUnit(1.0 / 10.0);

    sessparams.SetAcceptOwnPackets(true);
    transparams.SetPortbase(portbase);

    transparams.SetRTCPMultiplexing(true);

    status = sender.Create(sessparams, &transparams);
    checkerror(status);
    RTPIPv4Address addr(destip, destport, true);

    status = sender.AddDestination(addr);
    checkerror(status);

    std::string msg;

    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        printf("\nSending packet %d/%d\n", i, num);
        std::cout << "Enter message to be sent: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, msg);

        // send the packet
        status = sender.SendPacket((void *)msg.c_str(), msg.length(), 0, false, 10);
        checkerror(status);

        status = sess.Poll();
        checkerror(status);

        RTPTime::Wait(RTPTime(1, 0));
    }
```

Comment: This is a good writup of what you are trying to accomplish, but you don’t ask any questions. What part specifically do you need help with? Please post any code you have already written, and the community can help debug.

Comment: @szatmary

I want to encode the sequence of bitmaps into h264 and send over network (sender.SendPacket...line) and then receive the packet and decode the bitmaps out of it. And these bitmaps are received as memorystream and i do not want to have read or write operation on disk for this.

PS: I have edited above description to include code snippet.

Comment: I’m sorry, but statements are not questions. Yes, it is possible to send data over a web socket. It’s clear what you want to achieve, but I can’t do it for you. What question can I answer to unblock you?

Comment: Thanks.

how can I convert sequence of bitmaps into byte[] with h264 encoding and then extract the bitmaps from received byte[] with decoding?

Comment: You are asking how encode, then decode h264? x264, and libavcodec are well documented.

Comment: Yes I found that one, but my problem is with output sources and stream.
I can do encoding of image sequence into video with h264 using:
ffmpeg -i img%03d.png -c:v libx264 -vf fps=25 out.mp4

but for output it expects a location, which means I would have to write the output to a file and read it as byte[] and then send, which is going to be overkill for performance...

I am specifically looking for encoding the frames into stream without extra read write operation. I couldn't get proper documentation for libavcodec. Would appreciate if you can share some link for it.

Comment: Use a pipe, or look at dranger.com

Comment: What is a pipe?

Comment: A pipe is the most basic form form IPC going back to 1973. I fear you may be over your head on this topic. You’re sorta asking how to land a man on the moon without knowing about gravity.